# cant refresh the listView, what is wrong?

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh

On my dialog modify, only the delete works well and refresh well... my add dialog and edit dialog works well but doesn't refresh the `list-view`. How can I refresh this?

Below is my code snippet.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.school_screen);
        listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mySQLiteAdapter = new Database(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueSchoolAll();

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_school_button);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                updateList();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SchoolActivity.this, InsertSchool.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
        cursor.requery();
        String[] from = new String[]{Database.KEY_ID2, Database.KSCHOOL, Database.KSCHOOLCODE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rid, R.id.rt1, R.id.rt2};

        cursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_school, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_ID2));
                sdid.sdid(item_id);
                Intent intent=new Intent(SchoolActivity.this,DetailsSchool.class);
                startActivity(intent);  
                }

            });
        cursor.requery();
            listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_ID2));
                  AlertDialog.Builder myDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(SchoolActivity.this);
                  myDialog.setTitle("Modify");
                  myDialog.setMessage("Do you want to edit or delete?");
                  myDialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            mySQLiteAdapter.delete_byID2(item_id);
                            updateList();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(SchoolActivity.this,SchoolActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                  });

                    myDialog.setNegativeButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            updateSchool.id(item_id);
                            updateList();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(SchoolActivity.this, UpdateSchool.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                         }
                    });

                    myDialog.show();
            }
        });
            cursor.requery();
 }
 private void updateList(){
        cursor.requery();
 }
```

}

any help is appreciated

Comment: use notifyDatasetChanged() to refresh list-view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To udpate the listview with the new data, use

```
private void updateList(){
    cursorAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. .. where will I insert that line of code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Just call `updateList()` wherever and whenever you want to refresh the list with modified data.

Comment: Since you appear new here on StackOverflow, if you find an answer helpful, vote up the answer by clicking on "^" and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the "Green Tick" mark to the right of the answer. This will help others looking for same solution.

Comment: thanks my friend that helps ... I would like to vote but it says vote up requires 15 reputation.. :3

Answer (score 1):

in your updateList, make this change:

```
private void updateList(){

List<Data> newData = getYourNewData();
mAdapter.setList(yourNewList);
cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   

}
```

For more, you can watch this:

[Google I/O Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m38s)